# Yii form textarea character limit

Tags: php, forms, yii, textarea

I am trying to implement limit the character by showing to user in textarea. But this code snippet seems like not working. Please help me to find the error.

```
 <?php echo $form->textArea($model, 'tr_summary', array('rows' => 2, 'cols' => 50, 'class' => 'form-control fldRequired')); ?>
<div class="errorMessage Tour_tr_summary"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(".fldRequired").keyup(function(e) {
  fldId = $(this).attr('id');
  if(fldId == 'Tour_tr_summary' && $(this).val().length > 20) {
    $('.'+fldId).html( 'Maximum 20 characters allowed');
    e.preventDefault();
  }
 });

 </script>
```

this coding work perfectly for textfield but not textarea.

Comment: Do you have solved your question?

Answer (score 0):

No javascript is needed if you don't care for old browsers. Just add to textArea() one more parameter:

```
array('maxlength'=>10)
```

Not sure which version of Yii you are using, but assuming from the code it's Yii 1.x
More information you can find here:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_maxlength.asp
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#textArea-detail

Comment: Hello Mat, I was tried but it doesn't work. I heard there is no maxlength value for textarea. I am using Yii 1.1

Comment: there is no param "maxlength" in Yii, but there is in html5, it should work in most modern browssers. which browser did you check in? Did the generated html had the attribute maxlength="10" in the textarea?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this
In View,

```
<?php echo $form->textArea($model, 'Details', array('maxlength' => 300, 'rows' => 6, 'cols' => 50)); ?>
```

In model function rules(),

```
 array('Details', 'safe'),
 array('Details', 'length', 'max' => 300),
```

Comment: This techniques works only in submit. I want to try it while the user type in the textarea.

Comment: No, 'maxlength' => 300,  works while the user type in the textarea also. Please try.

Answer (score 0):

In your view, with JQuery, you can try with this or compare with your script. Main change is use JQuery id selector instead class selector. `Modelname` is your model class and `fieldname` is your attribute:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$('#Modelname_fieldname').keyup(function() {
        characterlimit();
});

function characterlimit()
{
        var text_max = 100; // Desired Character Limit
        var text_length = $('#Modelname_fieldname').val().length;
        var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

        if(text_remaining == 0)
        {
            $('#Modelname_fieldname').addClass('error');  
        }
        else
        {
            $('#Modelname_fieldname').removeClass('error');       
        }    
}
</script>
```